# adding 7 days to a date until end of month sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the first day of the month add 7 days and keep on adding 7 days not going over available days left in that month.
Example

```
July 1 – 7     --> 7 Days
July 8 – 14    --> 7 Days
July 15 – 21   --> 7 Days
July 22 – 28   --> 7 Days
July 29 - 31   --> 3 Days`
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL  @James

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you in a stored proc/trigger/etc doing some logic, or are you trying to return a specific result set with a query?

Comment: may it be that you do want to group by these "weeks"? please give us more information what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Could be generalized to not have to start on the first day of the month and there is probably a more compact way to do this, but this gets the job done.

```
declare @month varchar(2) = '10',
   @year varchar(4) = '2015',
   @fullWeekCount int;

declare @firstOfTheMonth datetime = @year + '-' + @month + '-1';
declare @daysInMonth int = datediff(day, @firstOfTheMonth, dateadd(month, 1, @firstOfTheMonth))
select @fullWeekCount = (@daysInMonth / 6)

declare @i int = 1,
    @startDate datetime = @firstOfTheMonth,
    @endDate datetime;

declare @dates table (StartDay datetime, EndDay datetime);

while (@i <= @fullWeekCount)
begin

    if (@i = @fullWeekCount)
        set @endDate = @year + '-' + @month + '-' + cast(@daysInMonth as varchar(2));
    else
        set @endDate = dateadd(day, 6, @startDate)

    insert into @dates (StartDay, EndDay)
    values (@startDate, @endDate)

    set @startDate = dateadd(day, 1, @endDate)
    set @i = @i + 1;

end

select * from @dates d
```